# Change the Focus Border color in Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind css with my react application. I am creating a form using tailwind and want to change focus border color of my input text box in teal which is blue.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main className="h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
        <form className="bg-white flex rounded-lg w-1/2">
          <div className= "flex-1 text-gray-700 p-20">
            <h1 className="text-3xl pb-2">Lets Get Started</h1>
            <p className="text-lg text-gray-500">We are herre to get you about our sdas no           bonsdcbeagufpi feqwifheqfwe</p>

            <div className='mt-6'>
              <div className="pb-4">
                <label 
                className="block text-sm pb-2" 
                htmlFor="name"
                >Name
                </label>
                <input
                className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500"
                 type="text" name="name" placeholder='Enter Your Name' />

              </div>
            </div>


          </div>
          <div> </div>

        </form>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I did change teal color with focus:boreder-teal-500 but it is not chaging teal color when I focus or click on my text box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can also do it directly with tailwind:

```
<div className="focus:border-blue border-2 border-solid" />
```

Answer (score 32):

You need to:

- Set your focus color (`focus:border-teal`)
- Remove the default outline (`focus:outline-none`)
- Then set (`focus:ring-0`), this removes the default ring that appears around the input element when it's focused.

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me.

Comment: this worked though but not changing colors yet

Comment: This should be the answer. Here's an example: ```<input class="focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:border-gray-900" />``` Like what is said above, the 1st removes the default outline, the second removes the ring and the third is the color you want. In this case a very dark gray.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without inline css? I have all my styling in separate files from my html.

Answer (score 6):

Input elements have an outline on focus by default. So your colored border is not visible.

Add `focus:outline-none` class to your input element to remove the outline.

```
<input className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500 focus:outline-none" type="text" name="name" placeholder='Enter Your Name' />
```

Answer (score 4):

It's called Focus:outline, Try focus:outline--gray-500

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight you contribute beyond https://stackoverflow.com/a/74747503/7733418 which provides the same basic solutio (different color) and an explanation, which yours lacks.

Answer (score 2):

Inputs are different. When working with inputs, you will need to change the outline, not the border.

RK007 response is another way to solve but requires some extra steps for the same effect, IMO.

```
            <input
            className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:outline-teal-500"
             type="text" name="name" placeholder='Enter Your Name' />
```

Answer (score 1):

I did just code to change a default focus blue color to turquoise by doing below↓

`focus:ring-turquoise-500 focus:border-turquoise-500`

Answer (score 1):

just add outline-none if you want to manipulate the border only in normal and focus states

`<input className="border-2 outline-none border-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:border-teal-500" type="text" name="name" placeholder='Enter Your Name' />`

you can also use the ring instead :

`<input className="ring-1 outline-none ring-gray-500 p-2 rounded-md w-1/2 focus:ring-teal-500 invalid:ring-red-500" type="text" name="name" placeholder='Enter Your Name' />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the border color wasn't changing and I fixed it by using `focus:ring-yellow-500` for `ring`.

All the related classes for everyone who is still challenging to this situation:

`<input className="focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-yellow-700" />`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this helped me

```
focus:ring-0 focus:border-[#cfe5fb] focus:border-transparent
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue.

```
 focus:border-fuchsia-600  focus:outline-none border-2 border-solid border-slate-800
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you want to change the border?

If so, it is super easy to do in css:

p{
color: white
}

```
p:hover{
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question (the OP asked specifically for the focus border color, not hover (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)